# android SQLite database with databse on specific location possible?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-sdcard

I am working on an APP which require database, I have created database and it accepts the query, creates the database, and I am able to do all operations.
following is the database which works:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sandeep.db";

// Table name
private static final String TABLE_C = "table_data";

// Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_C + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
 }
}
```

The database gets created in default location /data/dataapp_name/ but I cannot access it due to unrooted phone.

my Problem: 
1. how to create sandeep.db on sdcard or on phone memory which is publicly accessible?
2. Can I create a Whatsapp like folder and have my database reside in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method named `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)`.
 It will allow you to create database on sdcard.

You need to add following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml ,

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Comment: Thank You @vigbyor for your reply.
can you suggest me any example or link of the same?

Comment: Sure,but first try your self then I will give you links with working example.

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` would not be giving me external directory path on emulator. Am I right ?

Comment: does not work.
`File file_str = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`
`String DATABASE_FILE_PATH = file_str.toString();`
using this i m not able to pass string path

Comment: have you given the permission to read SD card in Androidmanifest.xml ?

Comment: yes already given. App crashes. 
I can provide edited code which is a constructor of Databasehelper class..

Comment: A link or example would help my case.. @vigbyor

Comment: If I use default SQLiteOpenHelper, where do I call this method? I am not so experienced, so help anyhelp would be welcome.

Comment: SQLLiteOpenHelper has predefined menthod named `onCreate()`, just override it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44696/discussion-between-sandeep-pareek-and-vigbyor)

Comment: How can I implement this? Please provide link of any working tutorial. I am using SQLiteOpenHelper.