# Add sqlite of Android to iPhone in xcode

Tags: android, iphone, sqlite

I have a sqlite database that I use in android and I open it using sqlite browser, I want to create same app in iPhone. I'm wondering how can I use the sqlite file of android in xcode5 for iPhone?

Comment: Simple suggestion is , copy your .db file into your SD-card folder and then pullout that .db file and push it into your iPhone.  Visit this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20948760/2567598)

Comment: could you explain the steps,please.

Comment: Please read it properly, I have explained you in step by step only.

Comment: What is the path of SD-card folder?

Comment: it will be logical path like /mnt/sdcard/... which can be vary. For some devices it starts with /sdcard/....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add the .sqlite file in main bundle. Go to Targets-> Build Phase -> Copy Bundle resource and then click + sign at bottom left.**

[image]

**Click the Add Other and choose the destination of .sqlite file**

[image]

**Now you can read the content of the file using the below code.**

```
    NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IOSMeeting" ofType:@"sqlite"];

    if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK) {

        NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");

    }
```

Comment: it should read! why don't you try it with your sqlite file, will hardly take 5-10 minutes.

Comment: if I'm trying to update data in this database by (UPDATE query), it is not work. Could you help me in this issue?